# Put form inputs in the same line fails after 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form inputs and I want to add some extra inputs in the same line when I press the add button (input name2, name3).

I have done [this](http://www.bootply.com/qME5Vd2Qr2) which works if I pressed the add button once. After 2 times the alignment is broken..

```js
var counter6=0;

$('#formType1')
.on('click', '.addButton6', function() {
        counter6++;
        var $template = $('#dose1 .col-md-1.col-sm-2'),
        $clone    = $template
                        .clone()
                        .removeClass('hide')
                        .removeAttr('id')
                        .attr('data-dose1-index', counter6)
                        .insertBefore($template.parent());
                
        // Update the name attributes
        $clone
            .find('[name="strofes"]').attr('name', 'strofes-' + counter6).end();
            
         var $template = $('#dose2 .col-md-1.col-sm-2'),
        $clone    = $template
                        .clone()
                        .removeClass('hide')
                        .removeAttr('id')
                        .attr('data-dose1-index', counter6)
                        .insertBefore($template.parent()); 
                    
          $clone
            .find('[name="uesi"]').attr('name', 'uesi-' + counter6).end();   
    })

    // Remove button click handler
    .on('click', '.removeButton6', function() {
        counter6 = counter6-1;
        var $row  = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
            index = $row.attr('data-dose1-index');
            
        // Remove element containing the fields
        $row.remove();
       
       
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <form id="formType1" method="post" action="workplan?action=form1S_submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <label style="font-size: 16px; color: #C0506C;">TITLE</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="form-group">  
                      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">name1</label>
                      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1">                      
                          <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="" required="" type="number">
                      </div>
                          
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">  
                      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">name2</label>
                      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1">                      
                          <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="strofes" required="" type="number">
                      </div>
                      <div id="dose1" class="form-group hide">
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 ">                      
                                <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="strofes" required="" type="number">
                          </div>
                        
                        
                           <div class="col-xs-1">
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton6"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                      </div>
                      
                      
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">  
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">name3</label>
                      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">                      
                          <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="uesi" required="" type="number">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-offset-1"> </div>
                    <div id="dose2" class="form-group hide">
                     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 ">                      
                         <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="uesi" required="" type="number">
                     </div>
                      
                       
                  </div>
                          
                    </div>
                     
                    <div class="form-group">  
                      
                      <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">name4</label>
                      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">                      
                          <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="" required="" type="number">
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="col-xs-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton6"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
</fieldset>
 </form>
               </div>
                    </div></div>
```

Comment: I haven't added yet the remove button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the classes you are using to clone the template. You have to made some changes to your script and your HTML. The changes are mentioned below-

1- Replace first occurrence of $template and $clone with this one

```
var $template = $('#dose1'),
        $clone    = $template
                        .clone()
                        .removeClass('hide')
                        .removeAttr('id')
                        .attr('data-dose1-index', counter6)
                        .insertBefore($template);
```

2- Replace Second occurrence of $template and $clone with this one

```
var $template = $('#dose2'),
        $clone    = $template
                        .clone()
                        .removeClass('hide')
                        .removeAttr('id')
                        .attr('data-dose2-index', counter6)
                        .insertBefore($template);
```

Here i am getting innerHTML of #dose1 and #dose2 and inserting it before their parent div.

3- In HTML replace #dose2 div with this one

```
<!----- #dose1--->
<div id="dose1" class="hide">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 ">                      
       <input min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="strofes" required="" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton6"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
     </div>
  </div>

<!------- #dose2 ----------->

<div id="dose2" class="hide">
   <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2">                      
       <input type="number" min="0" step="0.1" class="form-control" name="uesi" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-1">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton6"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added the remove button and it doens't appear at all http://www.bootply.com/tmKK2LXoFF

is it because you change the `$('#dose2 .col-md-1.col-sm-2'),` ?

Comment: @Nat95 Do you want to add 'remove' button with each newly created input or just a single delete button? also can you please update your code here, so that i can check it.

Comment: For every new inputs that are created, I want to have also a remove button. see here  http://www.bootply.com/uuIOnGQW4L

Comment: I changed also the script in the question

Comment: @Nat95 I have just updated my answer. Reverted the script to the one you originally posted and removed a class(form-group) form #dose1 and #dose2 divs. Also you need to replace the $row part of code with var $row  = $(this).parent().parent(), in your remove button handler  This should work now.

Comment: it doesn't work.. I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565569/remove-input-forms-with-button-fails in order to take points for your profile

Comment: @Nat95 can you tell me the exact problem. The code i suggested you is working here on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/f2tc0y13/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108885/discussion-between-nat95-and-shoaib-akhter).